# Typing in Android Studio produce 3 quotes instead of 2

Tags: android-studio

It seems like a stupid thing, but it very annoying and distracting:

I am typing code in java in Android Studio 4.1.1 and every time I try to enter some string I enter the Shift+' keys it makes just one quote like `"` (I am sure back in the days it was 2 sets and the cursor was in between them like `""`). I can totally just hit the ' key 1 more time, but then the **quotes become 3 instead of 2**!!!

When I try to type some words after the quote (when it's just one like `"`) it behaves very strange and ether removes the quote, or adds another one and type after that like: `""some word`

I looked in the settings for something to fix this but could not find anything, can anyone help?

Comment: Interesting, for me typing a quote produces a pair.

Comment: Before Android Studio update it did the same for me as well - a pair like  ```""```
But after I clean the Mac and installed all from scratch including Android Studio 4.1.1 - the problem is there :( I even imported my old preferences but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It was from the Mac's keyboard :( I used US-PC, switched to "ABC" and all is good now ...